# How to add custom drop-shadow with linear-gradient in tailwind css?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, linear-gradients

I am finding a way to add custom drop-shadow with linear-gradient in tailwind CSS. On looking the docs I found this

```html
<div class="drop-shadow-[0_35px_35px_rgba(0,0,0,0.25)]">
```

[over here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/drop-shadow)

But I want to use a `linear gradient` in place of a simple color.

I tried this

```html
<div class="drop-shadow-[0_0px_5px_linear-gradient( to right, #ffffff , #fffacc)]">
```

I also tried to change `taiwind.config.js` like below

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      dropShadow: {
        'xl' : '0px 0px 5px linear-gradient( to right, #ffffff , #fffacc)'
      } 
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**But both methods are not working.**

What am I  missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradients are images. So, they cannot be used as a color in CSS

Check this [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/hP6Lq1xTu2) for a solution

```html
<!--
  before:bg-gradient-to-*
  Gradient's direction

  before:from-*
  Gradient's start color

  before:via-* (optional)
  Gradient's middle color

  before:to-* (default: transparent)
  Gradient's end color

  To use custom gradient stops:
  Don't use before:from-*, before:to-*, and before:via-*.
  Change the Tailwind gradient stops variable.
  For example: [--tw-gradient-stops:red,blue,deeppink_80%]

  before:left-*
  Shadow's horizontal offset

  before:top-*
  Shadow's vertical offset

  before:blur-*
  Shadow's blur
-->

<div class="
  w-56
  h-56
  bg-white
  relative
  before:absolute
  before:w-full
  before:h-full
  before:-z-10
  before:bg-gradient-to-r
  before:from-[#ffffff]
  before:to-[#fffacc]
  before:left-0
  before:top-0
  before:blur-[5px]
"></div>
```